# Can you use VBA to populate a field in a csv whist maintaining the pre-existing data?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, row, data-conversion

first time asking anything on here I've been tasked to do something in VBA even though I have no experience in it.I have read through other articles which have helped me make some progress but I'm trying to extract some data from a spreadsheet say A10:M10 so a select few cells from one row I then have to get them in a pre-existing .csv that has a lot of fields already populated that wont change from use to use but I need to get the data from A10:M10 in to the csv equivalent of Z2:Z12 so a row to a column. Is this possible? So far I have only managed to get my code to populate a blank .csv with some headers but I don't really think it is feasible to for me to type out every value to every field. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Sub WriteFile()

  Dim ColNum As Integer
  Dim Line As String
  Dim LineValues() As Variant
  Dim OutputFileNum As Integer
  Dim PathName As String
  Dim RowNum As Integer
  Dim SheetValues() As Variant

  PathName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
  OutputFileNum = FreeFile

  Open PathName & "\file.csv" For Output Lock Write As #OutputFileNum

  Print #OutputFileNum, "Field1" & "," & "Field2" & "," & "Field3" & "," & "..." & "," & "Field26" 



  Close OutputFileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: is the code located in the workbook with the source range? Are you aware that the workbook containing this code needs to have an `.xlsm` or `.xlsb` extension? What is the name of the source worksheet? Are both files in the same folder? Best add the additional information by editing your post.

Comment: If you open the CSV in Excel you can update/add data without losing any of the other existing content. Then save and close the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Row to Column

```vb
Sub CopyRowToColumn()
   
    ' Source
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A10:M10") ' 13 cells hence 'Z2:Z14'

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dwb As Workbook:
    Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(swb.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "File.csv")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(1) ' the one and only
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("Z2")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Columns.Count)
    
    ' Copy values.
    drg.Value = Application.Transpose(srg.Value)
    
    ' Save and close.
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Row copied to column.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I got this to work thanks. How could it be amended to copy individual cells from the first workbook to the second? say A10 from source needed to go to A2 in the destination and also 4 or 5 more of individual cells needed to go across not in any particular order as in not always Column A to A? I'm sorry if this is really basic stuff I really appreciate and help.

Comment: This is only special since you are transposing (row to column or vice versa). Otherwise, it's much simpler e.g. `dws.Range("A2").Value = sws.Range("A10").Value`. I mean, you could have done the transpose cell by cell, right?